# How to use SharedObject from an external swf in AS2

Tags: flash, external, actionscript-2, shared-objects

I have a slideshow that everytime you press a button show a new slide. Every slide is an external swf's that is being loaded in to the main swf.

Inside every external swf there is a button that redirects you to another web page.

What i would like to do is use SharedObject (or something like it) to remember wich external swf that was last shown when the user pressed the button redirecting them to an other page.

How do i set the SharedObject in the external swf and then read it from the main swf?
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

does your container swf communicate with guest ones, maybe they have functions visible to each other? Also you can use `LocalConnection` for passing data to the main swf and storing it in the `SharedObject`.
[it's also possible to use one `SharedObject` by multiple swfs.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981777/actionscript-3-sharedobjects-dont-persist-across-different-swfs/3981899#3981899)