# AS3: Sharing data from a shared object between a flash application and a desktop Air application

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I created a shared object through a SWF file using this code:

```
var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("myProjectName");
```

and it can be shared by all SWF files (web or locally run on stand-alone player)

However, when I try to access the same SO from an adobe Air desktop application, it can't find any data inside it, it does not create a new Shared object with the same name.. it just does not see the stored data.

I tried specifying the path so it can be specifically shared by the two apps by doing this:

```
var so:SharedObject = SharedObject.getLocal("myProjectName" , "/myProjectName");
```

but I was getting this error:

```
Error: Error #2134: Cannot create SharedObject.
at flash.net::SharedObject$/getLocal()
```

any ideas, thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe what you want is possible. A `SharedObject` is specific to that app. They are meant to be sandboxed so other apps cannot access them (both to prevent naming collisions and for security reasons). Also, and I could be wrong here, but I believe AIR apps and SWFs store them in completely different base directories. Simply put, you **will not** be able to share these objects, not even between two different SWFs or AIR apps.

Relevant question: [ActionScript 3 SharedObjects don't persist across different swfs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3981777/actionscript-3-sharedobjects-dont-persist-across-different-swfs)